# Laravel 5.3.6 custom exception

Tags: laravel-5, exception

I'm busy learning laravel from a book for laravel 5.2.

I need to change some things because I'm using laravel 5.3.6 and I'm failing with errors.

I'm trying to create a custom exception when an admin user is trying to go to mysite/admin but the user is not active.

My code and errors: http://laravel.io/bin/PX5oP

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, changed my code in the admin middleware to this:
throw new NoActiveAccountException;

That solved the problem.